# How to hide href attribute of <A> tag via css when using window.print

Tags: javascript, css

I've a php page, with a button that able the user to print via window.print function.

I'd need to know how to hide the href attribute of an html  tag when printing the page

Example: 
if the tag  is like follow:

```
  <a href='myurl.com'>HELLO</a>
```

I want to display just HELLO.

I've to do this only when i use window.print.

I've already set up the css for printing in this way:

```
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility:hidden;
  }
  #section_to_print, #section_to_print * {
    visibility:visible;
  }

  #section_to_print {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }

  /*
  //HERE I NEED A RULE TO HIDE
  // ONLY HREF ATTRIBUTE BUT NOT CONTENT OF A TAG
  //BUT IN THIS WAY THEY HIDE THE WHOLE TAG OF COURSE
  #section_to_print a {
    display:none;
  } 
 */

  @page { size: landscape; }
}
```

And all works correctly, except for the link that was printed with the href part.

Thank you

Comment: You want to prohibit navigation? Or you don't want to show `href` attribute in client?

Comment: @PLB: *when printing*.

Comment: @ user: It's not normal behavior for browsers to show the link's `href` when printing. Are you sure you're not doing something in the CSS that makes it happen? Something like [what this answer describes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107408/printing-in-ie8-has-href-contents-inline) for instance? If so, then of course the answer is, don't do that. :-)

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? This has a reset file which adds the href value into the print CSS.

Comment: Yes i'm using bootstrap, it's correct what are you saying

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thank you, the solution i've found that work form me is similar to your

```
   #section_to_print a[href]:after { display:none; }
```

In fact, the problem was generated by some css containing a rule like follow:

```
     a:link:after, a:visited:after {content:" (" attr(href) ")";font-size:90%;}
```

Like suggested at this link:

stackoverflow.com/questions/4834517/…

However, thank to much :) Regards

Answer (score -3):

why dont you use:

```
#section_to_print a{
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the solution i've found that work form me is similar to your

     #section_to_print a[href]:after {    
        display:none;
     }

In fact, the problem was generated by some css containing a rule like follow:

      a:link:after, a:visited:after {content:" (" attr(href) ")";font-size:90%;}

Like suggested at this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834517/why-the-href-attributes-of-a-tags-are-printed-to-screen

However, thank to much :)

Regards,
Francesco

Comment: How to set post as SOLVED ?