# HTML page in print mode shows all the anchor links

Tags: php, html, cakephp

When I choose to print out any page of my web app, it gets printed with `<a>` links being visible.
That is very odd behaviour that did not happen before.

The only information I can provide right now is that the app is developed with cakePHP framework and that it happens for every link, no matter if it is text or image.

I attach a couple of code below:

```
<p>
   <a href="users/view/5668" class="username">John Doe</a>
</p>
<a href="users/add">
    <img src="/img/add_icon.png">
</a>
```

In the printable version it looks like this:

> /users/view/5668 John Doe

And what I need to be printed is just the `John Doe`

Any help, suggestions or guidance is much appreciated. If there is any other valuable information that I could provide, just ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "John Doe" and the add icon _should_ print. You should be asking about how to hide them.

Comment: Edited the question. What I need to hide is the exact link "users/view/..."

Answer (score 0):

@media print {
    a {
        display:none
    }
}
Edit###
Answered on the following post [SO post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613273/how-to-hide-href-attribute-of-a-tag-via-css-when-using-window-print)

```
a
```

{
content:attr(href);display:none
}

Comment: What it does is it just does not print anything. 
What I need is to print out only the "John Doe" without "users/view/5668"

Comment: Just found another question the same on here with the answer [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613273/how-to-hide-href-attribute-of-a-tag-via-css-when-using-window-print)

Comment: Revise your answer and add the note about `:after {content:...}` CSS from that question.

Comment: what about`@media print{ a[href]{display:none;}}`

Comment: It does not print the href content but it does not print the content that is in between `<a>` tags too.