# How to hide PHP URL link in CSS

Tags: php, html, css

Is it possible to hide the URL link that I use in php in order not to show to user to prevent user to change the URL link? And I'm using get function on another php page to retrieve the package ID.

Example I have a php URL code like this:

```
<a href="banner.php?packageID=1234" >
```

When user click on the link and lead to the URL, is that possible to hide the "1234" and just show banner.php?packageID= on the URL link only?

Please guide me through this. Thanks

Comment: Why not use server side URL rewriting, like Apache's .htaccess with mod_rewrite, or NGINX with a proxy rewrite, so you can link to `banner/1234`, and have your server, internally, rewrite it to `banner.php?packageID=1234`?

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible.  However, you can use rewrite rules to change the request URL such that it looks something like: **banner.php/1234**

A different approach would be to use a post request with a form, like so:

```
<form method="post" action="banner.php">
<input type="hidden" name="packageID" value="1234">
<button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

In this case, only the button is visible.  The button can be styled like a link,

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using .htaccess file, add following code

**Your .htaccess file**

```
options -multiviews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^banner/([^/.]+)?$ banner.php?packageID=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

**In PHP**

```
<a href="banner/1234" >
```

Answer (score 0):

in simple words it is not possible to hide that value from URL at all. Below are other approaches for you:

**Approach 1**

Use better URL like `banner/1234`

**Approach 2**

User title value instead of Id like `banner/banner-title`, I would suggest this.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the packageID in an encrypted format so that the user can't guess it or alter it.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the your problem.Its not possible to hide a specific attribute from the html tag using CSS.
You can see the below post also:
[How to hide href attribute of <A> tag via css when using window.print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613273/how-to-hide-href-attribute-of-a-tag-via-css-when-using-window-print)

Another options as above you can use packageID in encrypted format or url rewriting.

One more option, you can try it with javascript or jquery like below:

```
<a href="http://example.com/banner.php?packageID=" rel="1234" id="testurl" >testing</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#testurl").click(function(){
        var rel = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        window.location = href+rel;
        return false;
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use this:

`<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.location='banner.php?packageID=1234'" >`

or

`<a href="banner.php?packageID=" onclick="window.location='banner.php?packageID=1234';return false;" >`

But I don't think is the best way to hide URL,